# can't connect to swift-socket-client

Tags: swift, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to make a chat, but I can't connect.
server use node.js and socket.io version 3.1.1
I'm using the most recent version of Swift socket client, is it two versions of the error?
It's been weeks now without knowing the cause.
help me plz,,TT

When the connection is connected, when the connection is disconnected, when there is an error, it is on and shown in the log window.
emit ("test") is a test event that returns "test" from the server if the test event succeeds.

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
    
    static let shared = SocketIOManager()
    
    var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://myUrl.com")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    var socket: SocketIOClient!
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        socket = manager.defaultSocket
        socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/")
    }
    
    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
        test()
    }
    
    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }
    
    func test() {
        socket.on(clientEvent: .error) { (data, eck) in
            print(data)
            print(eck)
            print(self.socket.status)
            print("socket error")
        }

        socket.on("test") { (data, eck) in
            print("hihihihi")
            print(data)
            print("socket test")
        }
        
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) { (data, eck) in
            print(data)
            print("socket connect!!")
            self.socket.emit("test")
        }
        
        socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { (data, eck) in
            print(data)
            print("socket disconnect")
        }
    }
```

}

```
2021-02-09 18:41:26.292366+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
2021-02-09 18:41:26.292608+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
2021-02-09 18:41:26.292800+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
2021-02-09 18:41:26.292927+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
2021-02-09 18:41:26.293654+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: error
2021-02-09 18:41:26.293666+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854295] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://54.180.2.226:3000
2021-02-09 18:41:26.293785+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: test
2021-02-09 18:41:26.293796+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854295] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2021-02-09 18:41:26.293892+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect
2021-02-09 18:41:26.294001+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: disconnect
2021-02-09 18:41:26.294320+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854295] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://54.180.2.226:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
af
2021-02-09 18:41:26.364252+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2021-02-09 18:41:26.364448+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 0{"sid":"8K5NIimNyRJ-oQ33AAFh","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
2021-02-09 18:41:26.364897+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"8K5NIimNyRJ-oQ33AAFh","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
2021-02-09 18:41:26.369022+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: ping with data: []
2021-02-09 18:41:26.369032+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://54.180.2.226:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=8K5NIimNyRJ-oQ33AAFh
2021-02-09 18:41:26.369268+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketManager: Engine opened Connect
2021-02-09 18:41:26.369646+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Socket connected
2021-02-09 18:41:26.369886+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connected, 3]
2021-02-09 18:41:26.370293+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: connect with data: ["/"]
["/"]
socket connect!!
2021-02-09 18:41:26.371367+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Emitting: 2["test"], Ack: false
2021-02-09 18:41:26.371442+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll:  has data: false
2021-02-09 18:41:26.371803+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
2021-02-09 18:41:26.372298+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2
2021-02-09 18:41:26.372767+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
2021-02-09 18:41:26.372966+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling POST http://54.180.2.226:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=8K5NIimNyRJ-oQ33AAFh
2021-02-09 18:41:26.373433+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll: 2["test"] has data: false
2021-02-09 18:41:26.373660+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll: 2["test"] as type: 4
2021-02-09 18:41:26.409725+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854301] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 10:42["test"]
2021-02-09 18:41:26.410041+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854301] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
2021-02-09 18:41:26.410198+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854301] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling POST http://54.180.2.226:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=8K5NIimNyRJ-oQ33AAFh
2021-02-09 18:41:26.411327+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2021-02-09 18:41:26.411533+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854298] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://54.180.2.226:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=8K5NIimNyRJ-oQ33AAFh
2021-02-09 18:41:26.412691+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data: [["content-length": "18", "content-type": "text/html", "connection": "close"]]
2021-02-09 18:41:26.412823+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854296] LOG SocketEngine: Flushing probe wait
2021-02-09 18:41:26.422164+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854301] ERROR SocketEnginePolling: Error during long poll request
2021-02-09 18:41:26.422278+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854301] ERROR SocketEngine: Error
2021-02-09 18:41:26.422413+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] ERROR SocketManager: Error
2021-02-09 18:41:26.422436+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854301] LOG SocketEngine: Engine is being closed.
2021-02-09 18:41:26.422533+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854101] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["Error"]
2021-02-09 18:41:26.422547+0900 TikiTaka[17730:854301] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:1
["Error"]
<SocketIO.SocketAckEmitter: 0x60000148cb40>
connected
socket error
```

Comment: when did you calling establishConnection() i think in appDelegate right?

Comment: yes, now i solved matter,,

Comment: server's socket version is not match to me

Comment: can you please provide more details